# Store not loaded in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am usning below code to store the data from the ajax request but it is not lading data on the store so Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my store class:

```
    Ext.define("Por.store.Notes", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
        config: {
     storeId: 'Notes',
        model: "Por.model.Note",


    }
});
```

This is my model class:

```
    Ext.define("Por.model.Note", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'content_name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'kind', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'company_name', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'note', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'attext', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'cid', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'category', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'file_extension', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'mime_image', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'ciid', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'citem_name', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'attach', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'cryptic', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'url', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'is_socialsites_share_ok', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'skey', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lookup_id', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lookup_kind_name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'rid', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'content', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'clip_wm', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'vid_wm', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'flash_clip', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'module_num', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'itemtype', type: 'string' }
        ],

    }
});
```

This is ajax request which I am firing :

```
           Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: url,
            scope: this,
         callback: callbackFn

           success: function(response) {

                 var responseData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                 var store = Ext.getStore('Notes');
           store.setData(responseData);
           store.sync();    

            },

    failure:function(response){
        alert(response.status);
    }
        });
```

This is my view:

```
Ext.define("Por.view.NotesListContainer", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    alias: "widget.noteslistcontainer",

    initialize: function () {

        this.callParent(arguments);

        var notesTitle = {
        xtype: 'panel',
           html:'<div style = " text-align:center; padding-top:10px;" >First Data</div>'
        };

        var notesData = {
        xtype: 'panel',
           html:'<div style = " padding-left:15px;">Personalized Content for ARP</div>'
        };
```

This is my list view:

```
        var notesList = {
            xtype: "noteslist",
            store: Ext.getStore("Notes"),
            listeners: {
                itemtap: { fn: this.onNotesListDisclose, scope: this }
            }
        };

        this.add([notesTitle,notesData, notesList]);
    },
    onNewButtonTap: function () {
        console.log("newNoteCommand");
        this.fireEvent("newNoteCommand", this);
    },
    onNotesListDisclose: function(dv, index, item, record) {
        console.log("editNoteCommand");
        this.fireEvent('editNoteCommand', this, record);
    },
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define("Por.view.NotesList", {
    extend: "Ext.dataview.List",
    alias: "widget.noteslist",
    config: {
        loadingText: "Loading Notes...",
        emptyText: "<div class=\"notes-list-empty-text\">No notes found.</div>",
        onItemTap: true,
        itemTpl:'<div ><div style="font-size:14px;color: #5090D0;font-weight:bold;">{content_name}</div><div style = 

"clear:both;"></div></div><div><p style="font-size:12px;"> <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;"><b>Type:  </b></span> {company_name} 

</p></div><div><p style="font-size:12px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;border:1px solid red;">Account:  </span> 

{lookup_kind_name} </p></div></div>'        
    }
});
```

Here is the json data:

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "56636",
    "content_name": "Ray Zor interview",
    "kind": "0",
    "company_name": "The Gillette Company",
    "note": "<b>Business Problem<\/b> d\r\n* Inadequate collaboration infrastructure\r\n* 100% year over year growth\r\n* Lost sales due to service issues \r\n\r\n<b>Solution<\/b>\r\n* Apollo suite v7 with Oracle add-in\r\n* AppAccelerator for SQL\r\n* Solution Consulting engagement\r\n\r\n<b>Results<\/b>\r\n* 30% in time to market process\r\n* 25% improvement in customer sat scores\r\n* Better utilization of existing IT staff",
    "attext": null,
    "cid": null,
    "category": "Listen",
    "file_extension": "rref",
    "mime_image": null,
    "ciid": null,
    "citem_name": null,
    "attach": null,
    "cryptic": "48737f98c5172",
    "url": null,
    "is_socialsites_share_ok": null,
    "skey": null,
    "lookup_id": "-1",
    "lookup_kind_name": "Recorded Audio Reference",
    "rid": "56636",
    "content": "a wma is loaded to this topic",
    "clip_wm": "48738147342c1.wma",
    "vid_wm": "",
    "flash_clip": "",
    "module_num": 0,
    "itemtype": "listen"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either put `autoLoad: true` in the store

OR

```
store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // the operation object contains all of the details of the load operation
        console.log(records);
    },
    scope: this
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `proxy` and `reader` for `Por.store.Notes`. Define these configurations like -

```
Ext.define("Por.store.Notes", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        storeId: 'Notes',
        model: "Por.model.Note",
        proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            url : url,
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                rootProperty: "data"
            }
        }
    }        
});
```